# StackOverflowError caused by memoized Fibonacci on Clojure

Tags: clojure, dynamic-programming, memoization

**Config**

Tested under *clojure 1.10.3* and *openjdk 17.0.1*

**Problem**

Below is the slightly revised version of the [memoized Fibonacci](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize#example-5530eceee4b01bb732af0a83), and the general techniques refer to
wiki [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

```clj
(def fib
  (memoize #(condp = %
              0 (bigdec 0)
              1 1
              (+ (fib (dec %)) (fib (- % 2))))))

(fib 225) ; line 7
```

I had thought that the above `memoized Fibonacci` in *FP* like *Clojure* would act in spirit as the equivalent to the imperative [DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) e.g. in *Python* below,

```py
def fib(n):
    dp = [0, 1] + [0] * n
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2]
    return dp[n]
```

**Question 1**

Why did I actually get the following error when Fibonacci number was raised to *225* in my case?

```
Syntax error (StackOverflowError) compiling at 7:1
```

I also tried on the drop-in replacement *memo* on [core.memoize](https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize) and got the same error when Fibonacci number was raised to *110*.

**Tracing**

Below I added tracing the recursive outlooks of the `naive Fibonacci` vs. the `memoized Fibonacci`,

```clj
(ns fib.core)

(defn naive-fib [n]
  (condp = n
    0 (bigdec 0)
    1 1
    (+ (naive-fib (dec n)) (naive-fib (- n 2)))))

(def memo-fib
  (memoize #(condp = %
              0 (bigdec 0)
              1 1
              (+ (memo-fib (dec %)) (memo-fib (- % 2))))))

(in-ns 'user)

(require '[clojure.tools.trace :refer [trace-ns]])
(trace-ns 'fib.core)

(fib.core/naive-fib 5)
(println)
(fib.core/memo-fib 5)
```

Overlapping sub-problems from the `naive Fibonacci` were clearly eliminated by the `memoized Fibonacci`. Nothing seemed suspicious to cause *StackOverflowError* at the first sight, the depth of the stack frames for the `memoized Fibonacci` was strictly linear to the input number *n*, and the width was limited to *1*.

```
TRACE t427: (fib.core/naive-fib 5)
TRACE t428: | (fib.core/naive-fib 4)
TRACE t429: | | (fib.core/naive-fib 3)
TRACE t430: | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 2)
TRACE t431: | | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 1)
TRACE t431: | | | | => 1
TRACE t432: | | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 0)
TRACE t432: | | | | => 0M
TRACE t430: | | | => 1M
TRACE t433: | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 1)
TRACE t433: | | | => 1
TRACE t429: | | => 2M
TRACE t434: | | (fib.core/naive-fib 2)
TRACE t435: | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 1)
TRACE t435: | | | => 1
TRACE t436: | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 0)
TRACE t436: | | | => 0M
TRACE t434: | | => 1M
TRACE t428: | => 3M
TRACE t437: | (fib.core/naive-fib 3)
TRACE t438: | | (fib.core/naive-fib 2)
TRACE t439: | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 1)
TRACE t439: | | | => 1
TRACE t440: | | | (fib.core/naive-fib 0)
TRACE t440: | | | => 0M
TRACE t438: | | => 1M
TRACE t441: | | (fib.core/naive-fib 1)
TRACE t441: | | => 1
TRACE t437: | => 2M
TRACE t427: => 5M

TRACE t446: (fib.core/memo-fib 5)
TRACE t447: | (fib.core/memo-fib 4)
TRACE t448: | | (fib.core/memo-fib 3)
TRACE t449: | | | (fib.core/memo-fib 2)
TRACE t450: | | | | (fib.core/memo-fib 1)
TRACE t450: | | | | => 1
TRACE t451: | | | | (fib.core/memo-fib 0)
TRACE t451: | | | | => 0M
TRACE t449: | | | => 1M
TRACE t452: | | | (fib.core/memo-fib 1)
TRACE t452: | | | => 1
TRACE t448: | | => 2M
TRACE t453: | | (fib.core/memo-fib 2)
TRACE t453: | | => 1M
TRACE t447: | => 3M
TRACE t454: | (fib.core/memo-fib 3)
TRACE t454: | => 2M
TRACE t446: => 5M
```

**Question 2**

Why could *Clojure* assert at *compile-time* that the depth of merely *225* stack frames for the `memoized Fibonacci` in my case could potentially explode the whole *JVM* stack thus cease to run the recursion altogether? From the source code on *memoize* below, I could see that an empty *hashmap* was initiated to cache the arguments and the returns for the `memoized Fibonacci`. Did the said *hashmap* cause the assertion of *StackOverflowError*? Why?

```clj
(defn memoize
  "Returns a memoized version of a referentially transparent function. The
  memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from arguments
  to results and, when calls with the same arguments are repeated often, has
  higher performance at the expense of higher memory use."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (if-let [e (find @mem args)]
        (val e)
        (let [ret (apply f args)]
          (swap! mem assoc args ret)
          ret)))))
```

**Others** - *(for the sake of completeness but unrelated to the OP)*

We can take advantage of *loop recur* to achieve something like [TCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), or the [laziness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) of *iterate* [implementation](https://speakerdeck.com/m0wfo/dynamic-programming-plus-clojure?slide=18).

```clj
(ns fib.core)

(defn tail-fib [n]
  (loop [n n
         x (bigdec 0)
         y 1]
    (condp = n
      0 0
      1 y
      (recur (dec n) y (+ x y)))))

(defn lazy-fib [n]
  (->> n
       (nth (iterate (fn [[x y]]
                       [y (+ x y)])
                     [(bigdec 0) 1]))
       first))

(in-ns 'user)

(require '[clojure.tools.trace :refer [trace-ns]])
(trace-ns 'fib.core)

(fib.core/tail-fib 2000)
(println)
(fib.core/lazy-fib 2000)
```

The tracing tells that they don't make any recursive call longer in effect.

```
TRACE t471: (fib.core/tail-fib 2000)
TRACE t471: => 4224696333392304878706725602341482782579852840250681098010280137314308584370130707224123599639141511088446087538909603607640194711643596029271983312598737326253555802606991585915229492453904998722256795316982874482472992263901833716778060607011615497886719879858311468870876264597369086722884023654422295243347964480139515349562972087652656069529806499841977448720155612802665404554171717881930324025204312082516817125M

TRACE t476: (fib.core/lazy-fib 2000)
TRACE t476: => 4224696333392304878706725602341482782579852840250681098010280137314308584370130707224123599639141511088446087538909603607640194711643596029271983312598737326253555802606991585915229492453904998722256795316982874482472992263901833716778060607011615497886719879858311468870876264597369086722884023654422295243347964480139515349562972087652656069529806499841977448720155612802665404554171717881930324025204312082516817125M
```

Comment: You meant to say `defn` instead of `def`?

Comment: yes, it's typo. corrected.

Comment: updated the typo from `def fib [n]` to `def fib`. `memoize` returns a function.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, you should post multiple questions. If you keep
adding new things to your question, you invalidate answers. It's great, that
you do your own research and add your insights, but please keep the focus.  The
reason for your "compile time" error is, that your code runs at top level.
This is the way the clojure compiler works: it _runs_ the code in the ns and
keeps the artifacts (the byte code).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've carefully investigated the problem and finally figured it out, hopefully.

At first, let's look at a comparable yet handy recursive implementation on `memoized Fibonacci` in *Python*, before we jump into study on it in *Clojure*.

```py
def memo_fib(n):
    def fib(n):
        print(f"ALL: {n}")
        if n not in dp:
            print(f"NEW: {n}")
            if n == 0:
                dp[0] = 0
            elif n == 1:
                dp[1] = 1
            else:
                dp[n - 1], dp[n - 2] = fib(n - 1), fib(n - 2)
                dp[n] = dp[n - 1] + dp[n - 2]
        return dp[n]

    dp = {}
    return fib(n)


memo_fib(5)
```

We add two *print* clauses to trace the recursive executions on `memoized Fibonacci`. `ALL` denotes what actually enter the spawned call stacks even if they are already memoized, while `NEW` denotes what proportionally show up only if they have yet to *memoize*. Obviously, the total `ALL` steps are greater than the `NEW` ones, which is also evident on the output below,

```
ALL: 5
NEW: 5
ALL: 4
NEW: 4
ALL: 3
NEW: 3
ALL: 2
NEW: 2
ALL: 1
NEW: 1
ALL: 0
NEW: 0
ALL: 1
ALL: 2
ALL: 3
```

Let's also compare it to `naive Fibonacci` in *Python* below,

```py
def naive_fib(n):
    print(f"NAIVE: {n}")
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return naive_fib(n - 1) + naive_fib(n - 2)


naive_fib(5)
```

We can see below that `memoized Fibonacci` does reduce the recursive steps thus improve the stack more efficiently over `naive Fibonacci`, which invalidates the explanation @Eugene Pakhomov posted:

> Memoization does not affect the stack when the cache is empty.

```
NAIVE: 5
NAIVE: 4
NAIVE: 3
NAIVE: 2
NAIVE: 1
NAIVE: 0
NAIVE: 1
NAIVE: 2
NAIVE: 1
NAIVE: 0
NAIVE: 3
NAIVE: 2
NAIVE: 1
NAIVE: 0
NAIVE: 1
```

Back to `memoized Fibonacci` in *Clojure*, what we have been able to trace in the OP are just the `NEW` steps. To peek at the `ALL` steps, we have to trace `memoize` function itself inside out. Please help if you know how to do it conveniently.

Now it's time to conclude that `memoize` can help reduce repetitive recursive calls but it cannot entirely prevent recursive calls from spawning stack frames again and again for some of overlapping sub-problems. *StackOverflowError* emerges to surprise you if those sub-problems grow rapidly.

Comment: _which invalidates the explanation @Eugene Pakhomov posted_  With respect to stack overflows, no it does not. Stack overflows happen when a stack grows too deep. Calling a memorization recursive fib with an empty cache will still need to recur N times, once, on the (n-1) side. But then all the calls on (n-2) will already have cached answers.

Comment: The clause that @Eugene Pakhomov put was simply `Memoization does not affect the stack when the cache is empty` without details. I would say it's misleading than wrong. What you mentioned and I investigated nailed down the hidden root causes.

Answer (score 5):

Memoization does not affect the stack when the cache is empty. Your Clojure code is not equivalent to the Python code because the Clojure version is recursive while the Python version is iterative.

Answer (score 1):

[`Memoize`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize) returns function, so you have to use `def`:

```
(def fib
  (memoize #(condp = %
              0 (bigdec 0)
              1 1
              (+ (fib (dec %)) (fib (- % 2))))))

(fib 225)
=> 47068900554068939361891195233676009091941690850M
```

Comment: I mistakenly updated the OP from `def` to `defn`  in a hurry when @akond asked to verify. Now the OP is restored. I always get StackOverflowError in my case. Would you mind your raising Fibonacci number further e.g. to 2000 to check the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why on a fresh repl

```
(def fib
  (memoize #(condp = %
          0 (bigdec 0)
          1 1
          (+ (fib (dec %)) (fib (- % 2))))))
```

(fib 136) gives me an overflow
(fib 135) works fine
then when I do (fib 136) again I git no error.
Doing, from a fresh repl,
(map fib (range 1 10000))
works fine

Comment: I doubt that `memoize` initates a quasi-global atomic hashmap to store all the Fibonacci pairs {1 1, 2 1, 3 2, 4 3, 5 5, ...}, so `(fib n)` would lookup the values of fib_n-1 and fib_n-2 instead of repeating recursions starting off `(fib 1), (fib 2)` etc.

Comment: In short, `memoize` mimics what normally iterative DP does within recursive settings.

Comment: It indirectly partially answers my question - the said hashmap isn't the root source of StackOverflowError since `(map fib (range 1 10000))` works all the way down the line.